# the difference of having a relative pronoun

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> He is going to cut the part of hair (that) he dyed purple a few months ago in a barber shop.

I bracketed **that** cause it seems like placing **that** is optional,
if I omit the relative pronoun in this sentence ,
does ***he dyed purple a few months ago*** still act as an relative clause?

If we have **that** here, I can easily understand that:
He dyed part of his hair purple in a barber shop, and he is going to cut it,cause the PP in a barber shop belongs to the relative clause.

But if we don't have **that** in the sentence, will the meaning of the sentence slightly change? By which I mean would another interpretation appear without the presence of **that**?

Another interpretation could be: Part of his hair is dyed purple a few months ago, and he is going to cut it in a barber shop?

Comment: "That" is optional here.

Comment: And no other possible interpretations are created

Answer (score 0):

A jounalist told me just a few months ago when reading something I'd written that 'that' can be ommitted about 75% of the time where it is used. It had never occurred to me before, but she was right.

So yes, 'that' is optional. And if a word is optional, in many circumstances it is better to omit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit *'that'* here. Because a relative pronoun is *optional* when it modifies the object of the verb of the relative clause. Here, 'that' (i.e., *'hair'*) is the object of the verb *'dyed'*.

Therefore, *'that'* is optional in your sentence, and it means : 'He dyed his hair purple a few months ago in a barber shop, and he is going to cut the part of it.

Comment: typo: "...and he is going to cut **that** part of it"